# Removing dynamically added form fields

Tags: javascript

OK, I'm out of ideas here. I have some JavaScript that was apparently written by someone a while ago. In short, there is a button that calls a JS function. The function is to remove form fields that were added just prior. It works in IE 8 and older, but not in IE9 or FireFox. The function is:

```
function remove(salNum) {

    var fld
    fld = document.getElementById('salary' + salNum);
    fld.value = 0;

    document.forms[0].submit();

}
```

The output in the FireBug console gives and error:

```
fld is null
fld.value = 0;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: And how are you calling this function? Also, you declare the variable, then have a new line and then re-declare the variable...isn't that a syntax error?

Comment: Not sure if that's just a typo but you're missing a semi-colon after you define the fld variable.

Comment: David - it's being called from a form button: <input type="button" onclick="remove('<%=Counter%>');" value="Remove" id="Button3" name="Button3" />

Comment: Please provide a reproducible test case, e.g. via http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Ryan Your ASP/ERB code has no place here; show us what the actual HTML is that's calling the function, and the actual HTML being operated upon. (Or far better, a pared-down version of those that still shows the problem while removing irrelevant noise.)

Comment: ASP.NET + IE8 working... I fear some Microsoft evilness, here.

Comment: MaxArt - the script is old. I was hoping someone could see something in the function that looks depreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try this in case the element you are trying to remove has already been removed or the html has been altered:

```
function remove(salNum) {

    var fld
    fld = document.getElementById('salary' + salNum);

// check for element existance
if( fld ) fld.value = 0;

    document.forms[0].submit();

}
```

Comment: Although it no longer throws an error in FireBug, it still does not work; however, it still works in IE8.